# How can I use GWT snapshot builds in a Gradle project?

Tags: gwt

I wondered how to use the GWT snapshot builds in a gradle project. The snapshots are located here:
[GWT Sonatype artifacts](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... and I resolved it this way:

build.gradle:

```
repositories{
  maven{url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/'}
}

dependencies {
  implementation group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-user', version: 'HEAD-SNAPSHOT' 
  compileOnly group: 'com.google.gwt', name: 'gwt-dev', version: 'HEAD-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: Working example using gradle.kts
https://github.com/ibaca/rxsnake-gwt/blob/master/build.gradle.kts